# Pandas: customed rank function based on quantile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quantile

I have the following data frame.

```
   item_id   price  quantile
0        1     10      0.1
1        3     20      0.2
2        4     30      0.3
3        6     40      0.4
4       11     50      0.5
5       12     60      0.6
6       15     70      0.7
7       20     80      0.8
8       25     90      0.9
9       26    100      1.0
```

I would like to have a customed rank function, which starts from the record whose quantile closest to 0.44, then goes down, and goes up, then goes down, and goes up ...

The result should look like:

```
   item_id   price  quantile   customed_rank
0        1     10      0.1         6
1        3     20      0.2         4
2        4     30      0.3         2
3        6     40      0.4         1
4       11     50      0.5         3
5       12     60      0.6         5
6       15     70      0.7         7
7       20     80      0.8         8
8       25     90      0.9         9 
9       26    100      1.0        10
```

Other then looping over the entire data frame to do that, is there a more elegant way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about "goes up and then goes down".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to rank by the absolute value of the difference between `quantile` and 0.44.

```
(df['quantile'] - 0.44).abs().rank()
```

```
0     7.0
1     5.0
2     3.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     4.0
6     6.0
7     8.0
8     9.0
9    10.0
Name: quantile, dtype: float64
```

A faster (but uglier) alternative is to `argsort` twice.

```
(df['quantile'] - 0.44).abs().values.argsort().argsort() + 1
```

```
array([ 7,  5,  3,  1,  2,  4,  6,  8,  9, 10])
```

Note that this solution is only faster if you work with Numpy array objects (through the `values` property), rather than Pandas series objects.